# SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 57838 #0

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart, ip

I am developing an app on flutter using services of some external API.
When I go to use some of these external services I get this error :

```
DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 57838
#0
```

Below I am attaching the code relating to the above error.
Whenever I try to access the createWallet () function it shows up.

```
Future<String> createNewAddress() async {

    final walletRequest = (CreateWalletRequestBuilder()
      ..walletName = 'wallet'
      ..walletPassword = 'test'
      ..walletDriverName = '')
        .build();

    final handleTokenRequest = (InitWalletHandleTokenRequestBuilder()
        ..walletId = 'wallet'
        ..walletPassword = 'test')
          .build();


    final keyRequest = (GenerateKeyRequestBuilder()
      ..displayMnemonic = true
      ..walletHandleToken = 'aa')
        .build();


      final response = await algorand.kmd.createWallet(createWalletRequest: walletRequest);

      final handleToken = await algorand.kmd.initWalletHandleToken(initializeWalletHandleTokenRequest: handleTokenRequest);

      final address = await algorand.kmd.generateKey(generateKeyRequest: keyRequest);

      return address.toString();
  }
```

would anyone know how to help me? Thank you !

Comment: Take a closer look at the error message, it says you're sending the query to `localhost` (not to some external web server)

Comment: how can i change that field?

Comment: It's somewhere inside `algorand.kmd`

Comment: I didn't understand how to change this ip field ... with my ipv4 address or with the communication server's ip?

Comment: Nobody can help without seeing the code